# compress image (from public uri) before making request to google docs api with it

Tags: google-docs-api, image-compression

I'm trying to build a google doc programmatically from another source doc, and the source document contains pictures that are hosted on an s3 server.

So basically I'm getting the uri for the images from the source doc, then making my gdocs request directly with the uri like this:

```
  const request = [{
    insertInlineImage: {
      uri: myUriString,
      location: {
        index: 1
      }      
    },
  }];
```

My problem is that sometimes I'm getting this error back from the google docs server: 'Invalid request: The provided image is too large.'

I found in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#InsertInlineImageRequest) that "Images must be less than 50MB in size, cannot exceed 25 megapixels, and must be in one of PNG, JPEG, or GIF format."

So basically some of the images hosted on S3 that I need to copy to google docs are too large to make the request directly.

The problem is I don't really understand the best way (or if it's even possible) to compress the image between getting the uri from s3 and making the gdocs request (since I'm only really getting the uri, not the blob)

Maybe I need to do something like pull the image down, compress it, then save the compressed image again to s3, and then use the newly created url for the gdocs request?

That seems like a very round about thing to do, so I'm just wondering if anyone has a better solution.

My gut feeling is that there is something I'm missing or not understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reduce the image size and image data size, how about the following flow? This flow is used for reducing the image size and image data size using Google API.

#### Flow:

1. Download the image from the URL.
2. Upload the downloaded image data to Google Drive using Drive API.
3. Retrieve the thumbnailLink using Drive API.
4. Modify the image size of the thumbnail as follows.

   - The thumbnailLink is like `https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/###k=s220`.
   - Please modify this to `https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/###k=s1000`. `=s220` is modified to `=s1000`.
   - By this, the width of the thumbnail becomes 1,000 pixels.
5. Insert the image using the modified thumbnail link using Docs API.

#### Reference:

- [Principle of size of thumbnail link](https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp#principle)